# Softlayer: SoftLayer_Account::getAllBillingItems. Getting Empty Array [] when i pass "parentId" as null

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

working on **SoftLayer_Account::getAllBillingItems** passing Filter where I am getting all items with all child Items seperatly. But I want only parent items, so I included parentId as null in filter and I am getting **an empty array as result**. I am able to get items when I pass particular **ParentId**.

```
https://Username:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAllBillingItems.json?objectFilter={"allBillingItems":{"nextBillDate": {"operation": "betweenDate","options":[{"name": "startDate","value": ["03/07/2017"]},{"name": "endDate","value": ["03/20/2017"]}]},"parentId": {"operation":  null}}}&objectMask=category;location;associatedChildren;associatedChildren.category
```

I tried passing **is null** but no output.
Can some one help me? What's the operation to get all items with parentId null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation you need to use "is null" not "null" see https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

I noticed you are trying to get parent billing items with their children, I updated the object-mask in order to reduce retrieved data, take account that you could get errors if you are working with a large set of data. Review how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers. You can use any of the following masks:

```
objectMask=mask[id,parentId,category,location,associatedChildren.category]

objectMask=id;parentId;category;location;associatedChildren.category
```

But if you are trying to get only parent billing items, it’s not necessary to use mask unless you want data like category and location, on that case you can use following mask:

```
objectMask=mask[category,location]
```

This last will show you the information of parent item including the category and location.

You should be able to get parent billing items with their children using the following REST call.

```
https://<user_name>:<api_key>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAllBillingItems?objectFilter={"allBillingItems":{"nextBillDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["03/07/2017"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["03/20/2017"]}]},"parentId":{"operation": "is null"}}}&objectMask=mask[id,parentId,category,location,associatedChildren.category]
```

Take account that some REST clients don’t support blank spaces between letters. And finally, If you have a lot of billing items I suggest to use result-limit feature in order to avoid time out errors.

References:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-Masks
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item

I recomend you to read documentaqtion before going any further

Regards